# How to create a data frame where each element is an ordered factor?

Tags: r

I see that it is possible to turn strings into factors for each element in the data frame.

```
data.frame(..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
       check.names = TRUE,
       stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

How can I create ordered factors?

Comment: With the `factor` function

Comment: Do you already have them as ordered factors? If not, why can't you make them ordered factors before putting them into the data frame? (For one thing, if it automatically created ordered factors, how would it know what order to put them in?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is a data.frame, this will turn all columns into ordered factors (in the default ordering).

```
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, ordered=TRUE)
```

If you have more specific requirements as to the ordering you should make those need more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, if you have a dataframe `df` with character data in column `x`, you can use:

```
df$x <- as.ordered(df$x)
```

This is assuming that the default ordering is what you want, e.g.

```
> as.ordered(c("a","b","c"))
[1] a b c
Levels: a < b < c
```